# Extend rails new generator for a new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to use custom versions instead of the default 'Gemfile' and some standard assets (scss, js) when using

`rails new myappname`

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: thanks! that was quite elevating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RailsApps and specify a template using -m option.

```
rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

It will take you through a series of generator questions and create a project with starter packs!

One such question:

```
question  Template engine?
       1)  ERB
       2)  Haml
       3)  Slim
```

You could choose Slim incase you would like to use Slim for all the new views to be generated for the project.